# Automatically logging in to an account in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, autologin

I have an L5 application. I used `make:auth` to create the authentication functionality, and every user has an email, password, and account_number.

I've received a feature request to find a way for a user/admin to view accounts as if they logged in under a specific user. This is only for testing by the client.

I'm thinking it would best to create a route, say `/admin/{account_number}` and it redirects them the "You've logged in, So AndSo" page. However, I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Can someone chime in?

*Edit:*

With some pointers from terry low, I have this in my controller:

```
public function testLogin($account_number) {
    $user = User::where('account_number', $account_number)->first();
    $id   = $user->id;

    \Auth::login($user, true);

    var_dump(User::find(Auth::id())); // Returns the logged in User
}
```

But when I got to a protected page, I just get the login page, and not the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as an idea, you may use the method `\Auth::loginUsingId($id)`

an account_number should be able to links to users account, and you log them in using their id

Comment: I set up a route with this in it, thanks btw, and it tells me I'm logged in, but when I go to another route I'm redirected to the login page. Do you know how to bypass this?

Comment: i see, i thought you want something like preview a single page only,
you may using
`\Auth::login($your_user, $remember_me = false)` or $remember_me = true depends on your situation instead

Comment: Getting closer, but `\Auth::login($user, true)` doesn't carry over to other pages. It tells me I'm authenticated, but can't view other links.

Comment: i have tested, it is working, are you using laravel 5.2 ?

if so pls ensure your route `/admin/{account_number}` is assigned under `web middleware ` or else the session will not persists

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {`

   `Route::get('/admin/{account_number}', function ()`
    `{`

       `// your code to find the user under account_number`
        `Auth::login($your_user);`
    `});`

`});`

Comment: Thanks. I got it, finally. The reason your suggestions weren't working was that I was using `return redirect()->intended()` instead of just `return redirect()`. You were a big help, thanks.